# How to downgrade iPad 2 from iOS 5.1 to 5.0 for development

Tags: ipad, deployment, ios5.1, downgrade, ios5

I am developing an Application for iPad (iOS)on Xcode 4.2 on MAC OS X 10.6.5 i.e snow leopard and apple has not released sdk for ios 5.1 for snow leopard.

i was using my iPad for testing it was working great with ios 5.0.1.

i just recently upgrade iPad to 5.1 and now i am unable to deploy code on iPad , i checked the registration of my device for development on development.apple.com and its still exist.

i even checked in Organizer-Devices and in that window it show me following message :

```
The version of iOS on “My iPad” does not match any of the versions of iOS supported for development with this installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is available here.

OS Installed on My iPad
5.1.1 (9B206)

Xcode Supported iOS Versions
Latest
5.0 (9A334)
4.3 (8F190)
4.3
4.2
```

can anybody help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Click on your project name in the left top, then on your target, and then click on the "build settings" tab

In all the option there is a "iOS deployment target" i think this is what you want ^^

Comment: No, i have xcode 4.2 and in that we have sdk's till iOS sdk 5.0.
so it doesn't allow me to deploy my code on higher version that 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Turns out you have to download/install the newest version of Xcode from the App Store.

https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/checklist/

Comment: the problem is i don't have Mac OS X 10.7 i.e lion to download that.